# Rails Diffy Gem: How to Use CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using diffy ([click for github](https://github.com/samg/diffy)).  It's awesome, but I can't figure out how to add colors using the css is comes with.  The readme mentions it's possible to do this, but I'm not really sure how to leverage their css.

I'm pretty sure it's possible, since [this guy talks about it](http://drasticcode.com/2010/11/26/the-easiest-way-to-diff-two-strings-in-ruby).

Has anyone worked with diffy for colors before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your view, put :

```
<style>
  <%= Diffy::CSS %>
</style>
```

You can then copy

Comment: If using HAML, then write: `%style= Diffy::CSS` at the top of the view file.